# Functional trainer - is it worth to be one?

Tags: untagged

My wife has chosen to be a [functional trainer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_training) and is studying at the moment to have such a career. I my country (Ukraine) that kind of training is not a trendy profession. I doubt that she will be called-for enough.

So, I wonder, is it popular in USA and Europe? Is it a good choice of profession? Is it trendy enough in other countries?

Comment: Closing this as off-topic. From the FAQ, this site is *for professionals, but not about the profession*

Comment: So, there is no possibility to become a professional using this site? Weird... I thought all the SE sites are intended to help people become more professional.

Comment: This is no different than SO restricting questions to being about coding, as opposed to the software engineering profession. It's for professional coders, who use it to improve their skills, but not the "meta" about the profession.

Comment: Ok. I got it. Seems like one more stack exchange site is necessary: triainers.stackexchange.com for the same purpose as programmers.stackexchange.com exists. I belive it would be 'very' popular. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Functional" is a word without a strict definition, according to the accepted answer for the Question ["Are functional movement exercises healthy to do everyday?"](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3433/are-functional-movement-exercises-healthy-to-do-everyday). It's a great answer.

Over here in Germany, it's just one of many buzzwords created by the fitness industry. The word's usage a bit like "holistic" - anything can be "holistic" these days.

Aside from that, beware overpriced training materials and certification programs, I'd say